# Optimized 2D wavelet transform using FFT

Tags: c#, image-processing, optimization, fft, wavelet

I'm currenty aiming to optimize my fast wavelet transform (FWT) algorithm for 2D signals (images). It works as follows:

- one iteration of 1D FWT does convolution of 1D input data with a selected 1D filter (lengths from 2 to approx. 60) and downsamples the result
- algorithm for 2D transform does 1D FWT across all rows and then all columns of the input image
- it iterates if more levels are desired

The transform is a part of interactive application that demonstrates wavelets and their use. It works fairly fast and usually responds in real time to user's interactions. But if the filter is very long some performance issues occur. I've read that using Fast Fourier Transorm (FFT) instead of convolution is effective for long enough filters.

I've already implemented the 1D FFT, but the question is how to use it for maximum efficiency? Should I transform the input data before single 1D FWT, then perform convolution (which corresponds to multiplication in frequency domain), and then transform the data back using inverse FFT? <strike>Also, how is the multiplication done exactly? For example, the input data of length 256 and filter of length 4 are both transformed using FFT and then only the first 4 values of input data are multiplied before transforming the data back?</strike> I'm struggling a little bit on the details and would very much appreciate any insight into this.

**EDIT:**
I've figured out that in my case I'm after circular convolution, therefore the filter should be zero padded so that its length is the same as length of the input data. But my question about efficiency still holds. How should I use FFT for FWT computation in order to be beneficial?

**EDIT 2:**
This question was answered on [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28051/optimized-2d-wavelet-transform-using-fft).

Answer (score 1):

There's a really elegant way to do this. I could dig up the code I have for this if you're interested, made it ages ago (see these two publications [for the non-redundant(FWT) case](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8672838_Denoising_Functional_MR_Images_A_Comparison_of_Wavelet_Denoising_and_Gaussian_Smoothing) (fig 3) and [for the shift-invariant case](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/47364806_Polyphase_decompositions_and_shift-invariant_discrete_wavelet_transforms_in_the_frequency_domain)). The shift-invariant case may not be what you're after but it uses the same trick. it's described slightly more thoroughly [here in Appendix B](http://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/2976380/appendix.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check those articles out. However, I've already implemented optimized FWT algorithm using FFT. The computation speedup it provided was good in some cases, but overal the result wasn't satisfactory enough to use it (in my case). I might try substituing lifting scheme for FWT in the future, but as for now I made the application I'm developing usable by taking advantage of parallel computations runing on GPU (CUDA).

Comment: The method you refer to in the DSP mailing list (doing convolutions in freq domain) and the rest in the time domain is described by Rioul and Duhamel. Bit of a shame to do all the extra FFTs and iFFTs as subsampling and the rest can be easily done in the freq domain - but you will see that in the papers.

Comment: See this URL: https://github.com/amwink/bias/blob/master/matlab/spm_wavelet/fwt2ffwt.m